# I want to have extension for uiview to store property in swift

Tags: ios, swift2

I think this is just easy but I can't implement this.
In swift, extension can add methods or whatever but cannot add stored property?
Maybe you need to add new class or something but I don't know how to do this.
Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a custom View, you can do the following:

1 - Create a swift and xib files, both with the same name.

2 - On the Interface Builder, set the File's owner to the swift-file's class.

3 - Add the following code to the view's lifecycle methods:

```
import UIKit

class View: UIView {
    // YOUR PROPERTIES AND OUTLETS HERE ie.
    var nameLabel :UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        let object = NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType) as NSString
        let customNibName = object.componentsSeparatedByString(".").last!
        let v = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(customNibName, owner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
        addSubview(v!)
        v?.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do this without Xib and interface builder?

Comment: Yes! Just subclass UIView, you can create your CustomView with custom properties. Pretty simple. You can also add yous elements using code, take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage.html

Answer (score 1):

you can do this
Global:

```
import UIKit
let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
class Macro: NSObject {
}
```

Local property:

```
lazy var screenWidth : CGFloat = {
    let temp = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    return temp
}()
```